# Как объединить строки в visual studio на си

Tags: c, строки

Почему не получается склеить две строки в одну на visual studio на си? Он постоянно выводит мне исключение - Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'stroka1' was corrupted.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    char stroka1[] = "HLT";
    char stroka2[] = "DEF";
    strcat(stroka1, stroka2);
    printf("%s\n", stroka1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Потому что нужно выделить первой строке достаточно места, чтобы в нее можно было добавить вторую, не выходя за границы массива.

Answer (score 0):

Непонятно при чем тут Visual Studio.

---

> ... и результат записывается в первую строку

```
char stroka1[7] = "HLT";
...
```